# Building project with Premake5 doesn't generate executables or intermediates

Tags: c++, lua, premake

I recently watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sULV3aB2qeU&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dC-V-N3m0Go4deliWHPFwT&index=7%0A) video and decided to include a premake build step in my project. However, after seemingly implementing the code in my .lua file identically (apart from the names), premake doesn't generate the bin and bin-int directories. The strange thing is that the .sln, .vcxproj and .vcxproj.filters files are all generated.

my premake5.lua file:

```
workspace "OpenGE"
    architecture "x64"
    startproject "Sandbox"

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release",
        "Dist"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "OpenGE"
    location "OpenGE"

    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "GE_DLL_BUILD"
        }

        postbuildcommands
        {
            "{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox"
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "GE_DEBUG"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "GE_RELEASE"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "GE_DIST"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "On"

project "Sandbox"
    location "Sandbox"

    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "OpenGE/src"
    }

    links
    {
        "OpenGE"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "GE_DEBUG"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "GE_RELEASE"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "GE_DIST"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "On"
```

The output on the command line by running premake looks fine:

```
C:\Users\bonnl\source\repos\OpenGE>call dependencies\premake\premake5 vs2019
Building configurations...
Running action 'vs2019'...
Done (92ms).

C:\Users\bonnl\source\repos\OpenGE>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If any additional code or information is needed, I'd be glad to add it.

Comment: *"premake doesn't generate the bin and bin-int directories"*. Does obj dir and target dir in solution point to those directories? It would be visual which would create the directory during the build.

Comment: As remainder, premake doesn't build the solution.

Comment: Really? I guess I assumed that because it's called a build tool :)

Comment: It create stand alone (contrary to CMake) makefile/solution that you use normally afterward.

Comment: Yes I realized this in retrospect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I thought that premake will build my project as well as generate the solution and project files. I have since built the project and it works like a charm

Comment: How did you build the project? Inside visual studio or elsewhere? I'm having trouble with xcode not recognising the installed packages and headers.